# Non-interactive one-time ssh && scp for 100 servers

Tags: ssh, scp

I need to copy some data from a cluster of very restricted machines through the network which currently has DNS problems (so some connections are bizarrely not working).
I found that the only way to copy the data from a machine is running scp from that machine.
For now the workflow is:

1. for each machine in machines
2. `ssh machine`
3. enter password
4. `scp files destination:results`
5. enter password
6. wait
7. repeat forever

I'm going mad over this manual labor. I want a solution which allows me to enter the password a single time.
I've searched for solutions. Most recommend installing SSH keys, but this requires the same procedure to distribute the keys. Other mention the `expect` program, but I don't have it on that system.

How can this be accomplished?

**Update:**
The main machine runs FreeBSD 9 and the 100 servers run Ubuntu 12.
**I don't have root on any machine.**

Comment: Is there a different password for each machine?

Comment: The username and password are the same.

Comment: What OS are you using? If linux, which distribution?

Comment: @terdon The main machine runs FreeBSD 9 and the 100 servers run Ubuntu 12. P.S. I don't have root on any machine.

Comment: Make a habit of distributing your SSH public keys as soon as you receive access to any server through your life and you'll thank yourself forever. That said, when I receive access to large batches of servers at once I run: `for s in $LIST_OF_SERVERS; do ssh-copy-id $s; done` and put my password (plus newline) in the clipboard. Manual labor still, but goes by quiker, and, again will only need to be done once per server.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that these are all Linux hosts and that you have root access to them. I will also assume that they are using `apt` for package management, but it is easy to apply this solution with `yum` or `pacman` or any other package manager.

As far as I know, `ssh` offers no way of specifying a password on the command line so first you will need to install [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) on your local machine:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

This will allow you to pass the password as a command line argument:

```
sshpass -p '<password>' ssh user@server
```

Now, create a file with all the IPs you are interested in, one per line. You can parse this file to install `sshpass` on each remote machine. If your password is `foo` and you are connecting as `root`, you can do

```
while read ip; do 
 sshpass -p 'foo' ssh root@$ip "apt-get install sshpass"; 
done < ips.txt
```

`sshpass`is now installed on each server. Now, go through the servers again, and copy your files. If you are copying as `root` and the `root` password for your `destination` is `bar`, do this:

```
while read ip; do 
 sshpass -p 'foo' ssh root@$ip "sshpass -p 'bar' scp files dest:/results/"; 
done < ips.txt
```

---

You can also use `sshpass` to copỳ your key files and --as long as you've used an empty passphrase-- allow passwordless access so you don't have this problem next time around:

```
while read ip; do 
   sshpass -p 'foo' ssh root@$ip \
      "sshpass -p 'bar' ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@destination";
done < ips.txt
```

Once that is done, you will be able to copy the files over using:

```
while read ip; do ssh root@$ip "scp files dest:/results/"; done < ips.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed your answer. My problem is that I didn't have root on any machine. The main machine had FreeBSD 9 and the 100 servers had Ubuntu 12.

Comment: @Ark-kun that's a problem. You could simplify things by running the `scp` from your machine, that way at least you won't need to `ssh`: `scp user@ip:/remote/path /local/path`. Then, if you copy your password to the clipboard you can just middle click 100 times to enter the password.

Comment: At that time I couldn't run scp from the main machine because of some strange DNS-related problems. It only worked the other way. Thatnks for the suggestion. Does `sshpass` really require root?

Comment: @Ark-kun no, only to install it the first time.

Comment: I meant "Can your proposed solution be used without having root anywhere?" What if I build sshpass from source and skip the package manager? I guess no.

Comment: @Ark-kun huh, you probably could actually yes. Assuming the source ha a configure script that will take the `--prefix` option, you should be able to compile on each machine and install in your user directory.