# Use bash script to copy select txt files from remote server to my local machine

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords

I would like this script to NOT prompt me for a password when I run it. I would like to put a password inside the script that will pass by itself. This is not a root password: It is for an account set up specifically for this purpose.

```
#!/bin/bash
copyPath=/u/home/topp/Daily
destinationPath=/home/taliesin_oppenheimer
pass=Pass

scp user@host:$copyPath/UserLatency.txt $destinationPath/TXTfiles

scp user@host:$copyPath/ServerLatency.txt $destinationPath/TXTfiles
```

etc

Ideally, I would like to set a crontab that launches this script every morning, so i can parse the txt files on my local machine as soon as I get in to the office. When I run this right now, I have to enter my password for each file I copy.

Any pointers?

Thanks and best,

-Tali

Comment: Have a look [here](http://superuser.com/a/579140/151431).

Answer (score 5):

You should not store a password in a script. The best way to not have your script prompting for a password is to generate an authentication key with [ssh-keygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen) and then copy the public key to the remote server in $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys.

You can find a lot of tutorials to do this.